# Python program to read names and scores of the participants and to store in a file. write() to accomplish this task. File name- "output_data.txt"

Tags: python

```
n=int(input("Enter the number of students:"))
i=1
while i<=n:
    student=int(input("For students "))
    name=input("Enter name:")
    score=int(input("Enter the score:"))
    i+=1
    with open("output_data.txt","w") as f:
        f.write("name: "+ name + " Score: " + str(score))
    with open("output_data.txt") as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Right now the code is only returning one student instead of returning all of them. How do I get it to return all students that were added?

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("output_data.txt","w") as f:
        f.write("name: "+ name + " Score: " + str(score))
```

When you do this by opening file in `w` mode, it truncates the existing content and writes the file from the start. What you can do is:

```
n=int(input("Enter the number of students:"))
i=1
with open("output_data.txt","w") as f:
    while i<=n:
        student=int(input("For students "))
        name=input("Enter name:")
        score=int(input("Enter the score:"))
        i+=1
        f.write("name: "+ name + " Score: " + str(score))
with open("output_data.txt") as f:
        print(f.read())
```